# how to count seconds to 6:00pm in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I can not seem to figure out how to count the number of seconds to 6:00 pm for the current day. Need it to set the limit of a date picker so that the user can only pick a time from now until 6pm.

Working with NSDate seems to be painful at best.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `NSCalendar` class to perform some calculations for you. Code may look like:

```
NSCalendar* calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents* comps = [calendar components: NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];
[comps setHour: 18];
[comps setMinute: 0];
[comps setSecond: 0];
NSDate *pmDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:comps];
NSTimeInterval interval = [pmDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
```

Comment: NSTimeInterval is a double, casting this across to an int gave me the result.  Thank you :)

8 lines of code to count the number of seconds until 6pm... and I thought my wife was verbose.

Answer (score 0):

You can always fall back to C http://linux.die.net/man/3/mktime

Comment: I was considering that as a worse case. Not a fan of NSDate anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this (from [iphonedevsdk.com](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/12093-nsdate-isbetween.html)):

```
//NSDate_ext.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSDate (Extend)
- (BOOL)isBetween:(NSDate *)dateStart:(NSDate *)dateEnd;
@end

//NSDate_ext.m

#import "NSDate_ext.h"

@implementation NSDate (Extend)

- (BOOL)isBetween:(NSDate *)dateStart:(NSDate *)dateEnd {

    if ([self compare:dateEnd] == NSOrderedDescending)
        return NO;

    if ([self compare:dateStart] == NSOrderedAscending) 
        return NO;

    return YES;
}

@end
```

Check if the user's entered time is between the date range you specify.

Comment: Sorry this is a UI experience issue, need to change the viewable time range in the slider.

Thanks anyway.